# Haskell: concat a list of tuples with an element and a list: [(a,[b])] -> [(a,b)]

Tags: list, haskell, split, tuples, concatenation

I want to concat in a list of tuples of elements and Strings, each char with the element.

For example: [(True, "xy"), (False, "abc")] -> [(True,’x’),(True,’y’),(False,’a’), (False,’b’),(False,’c’)]

I do have a solution, but im wondering if there is a better one:

```
concatsplit :: [(a,[b])] -> [(a,b)]
concatsplit a = concatMap (\(x,y)-> concatsplit' (x,y)) a

concatsplit' :: (a,[b]) -> [(a,b)]
concatsplit' y = map (\x -> ((fst y),x)) (snd y)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why not a simple list comprehension?

List comprehensions can often do as much as higher order functions, and I think that if you don't need to change the data but only "unpack" it, they are pretty clear. Here's a working example:

```
concS :: [(a,[b])] -> [(a,b)]
concS ls = [(a,b) | (a,x) <- ls, b <- x]
```

Answer (score 3):

`sequenceA` makes it really easy:

```
concatsplit = concatMap sequenceA
```

Or generalize it even further:

```
concatsplit = (>>= sequenceA)
```

Details:

- `sequenceA` has type `(Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`. This means that if you have a type with a `Traversable` on the "outside" and an `Applicative` on the "inside", you can call `sequenceA` on it to turn it inside-out, so that the `Applicative` is on the "outside" and the `Traversable` is on the "inside".
- In this case, `(True, "xy")` has type `(Bool, [Char])`, which desugars to `(,) Bool ([] Char)`. There's [an instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#line-252) of `Traversable` for `((,) a)`, and there's [an instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-972) of `Applicative` for `[]`. Thus, you can call `sequenceA` on it, and the result will be of type `[] ((,) Bool Char)`, or `[(Bool, Char)]` with sugar.
- As it turns out, not only does `sequenceA` have a useful type, but it does exactly the thing you need here (and turns out to be exactly equivalent to `concatsplit'`).
- `concatMap` has type `Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`. `(>>=)` has type `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. When specialized to lists, these become the same, except with their arguments in the opposite order.

Comment: it'd add much value to the answer if you could expound a bit on the specific types and instances involved.

Comment: @WillNess I added some explanation.

Comment: great; can't uv twice. :) I don't know if that's an accepted terminology, but I usually say `sequence` "transposes" the types, or "flips" them. ("turns inside-out" also sounds nice.) here, it turns a pair with a list  into a list of pairs... so we have `concatsplit = (>>= (\(a,bs) -> (a ,) <$> bs))` and that's exactly the definition of the "pair" Traversable. Nice; thanks for making me work through this. :) another tricky example is `traverse (splitAt 1)` which does exactly what's expected of it from the types, like magic; simpler, yet nice, is `traverse ZipList` (cf. "transposes" above ;) ).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers show how to do this idiomatically from scratch, which I like a lot. It might also be interesting to show how you might polish what you've already got. Here it is again as a reminder:

```
concatsplit a = concatMap (\(x,y)-> concatsplit' (x,y)) a
concatsplit' y = map (\x -> ((fst y),x)) (snd y)
```

The first thing I'd consistently change is called "eta reduction", and it is when you turn something of the shape `\x -> foo x` into just `foo`. We can do this in the argument to `concatMap` to get

```
concatsplit a = concatMap concatsplit' a
```

and then again in the argument to `concatsplit` to get:

```
concatsplit = concatMap concatsplit'
```

Looking at `concatsplit'`, the thing I like least is the use of `fst` and `snd` instead of pattern matching. With pattern matching, it looks like this:

```
concatsplit' (a,bs) = map (\x -> (a,x)) bs
```

If you really wanted to practice your eta reduction, you might notice that `(,)` can be applied prefix and change this to

```
concatsplit' (a,bs) = map (\x -> (,) a x) bs
                    = map ((,) a) bs
```

but I think I'm just as happy one way or the other. At this point, this definition is small enough that I'd be tempted to inline it into `concatsplit` itself, getting:

```
concatsplit = concatMap (\(a,bs) -> map ((,) a) bs)
```

This looks like a pretty good definition to me, and I'd stop there.

You *might* be bugged by the almost-eta-reduction here: it's almost the right shape to drop the `bs`. An advanced user might go on, noticing that:

```
uncurry (\a bs -> map ((,) a) bs) = \(a,bs) -> map ((,) a) bs
```

Hence with some eta reduction and other point-free techniques, we could transition this way:

```
concatsplit = concatMap (uncurry (\a bs -> map ((,) a) bs))
            = concatMap (uncurry (\a -> map ((,) a)))
            = concatMap (uncurry (map . (,)))
```

But, personally, I find this less readable than where I declared I would stop above, namely:

```
concatsplit = concatMap (\(a,bs) -> map ((,) a) bs)
```

Comment: I very much like `TupleSections`: `concatMap (\(a,bs) -> map (a,) bs)`.  No essential difference but the one fewer pair of parentheses cleans it up a lot for me.

Comment: @luqui I prefer `(a ,)`, similar to `(f .)` over `(f.)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the monad instance for lists:

```
concatSplit l = l >>= \(a,x) -> x >>= \b -> return (a,b)
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
concatSplit l = l >>= \(a,x) -> map ((,) a) x
```

And reformatted to `do` notation

```
concatSplit l = do
  (a,x) <- l
  map ((,) a) x
```